# Не могу использовать значение переменной из одного файла в другом (C#)

Tags: c#

такая ситуация: проект состоит из двух файлов. В одном из них описаны классы и функции, в основном всё остальное. В первом задана локальная переменная, которая изменяется функцией.
В основном файле необходимо значение для вывода, но программа выдаёт ошибку "procent не существует в данном контексте".
Как это можно исправить?

Ниже прилагаю код.

Основной файл (тут и возникает ошибка):

```
using System;

namespace project{
    class Program{
        static void Main(){
            int age_0 = 0, salary_0 = 0, childrenMany_0 = 0, rating_0 = 0;
            string children_0 = "none";
            Credit client = new Credit();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте. Ответьте на несколько вопросов, чтобы мы смогли предложить вам процентную ставку по кредиту. Всё подсчитается автоматически. Минимальное значение - 1%, максимальное - 7%. Базовая ставка - 3%");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
            for(byte i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                switch(i){
                    case 0: System.Console.WriteLine("Сколько вам лет? (Введите число. Учтите, что вы должны быть старше восемнадцати лет.)");
                    age_0 = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine()); break;
                    case 1: System.Console.WriteLine("Сколько вы зарабатываете? (Введите число в единицах. Учтите, что ваша зарплата должна быть хотя бы 10000.");
                    salary_0 = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine()); break;
                    case 2: System.Console.WriteLine("Есть ли у вас несовершеннолетние дети в семье? (Введите букву 'д' (да) или 'н' (нет)."); 
                    children_0 = System.Console.ReadLine(); break;
                    case 3: if (children_0 == "д"){
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Сколько у вас детей?");
                        childrenMany_0 = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    } break;
                    case 4: System.Console.WriteLine("Каков ваш кредитный рейтинг? (Введите число: -1, 0, или 1, где -1 - 'плохой', 1 - 'хороший', 0 - 'никогда не брал кредитов'.");
                    rating_0 = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine()); break;

                } 
                client.check();
            }
            client.setValues(age_0, salary_0, children_0, childrenMany_0, rating_0);
            client.countProcent();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Ваша процентная ставка: " + procent);
        }
    }
}
```

Файл с классами и функциями:

```
using System;

namespace project{
    public class Credit{
        public int age;
        public int salary;
        public string children;
        public int childrenMany;
        public int rating;
        public static int procent_0;

        public void setValues(int _age, int _salary, string _children, int _childrenMany, int _rating) {
            age = _age;
            salary = _salary;
            children = _children;
            childrenMany = _childrenMany;
            rating = _rating;
        }
        public void check() {
            if (age < 18){
                System.Console.WriteLine("Вы слишком молоды чтобы взять кредит.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (salary < 10000){
                System.Console.WriteLine("Вашего заработка недостаточно, чтобы считать вас платёжеспособным клиентом.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (children != "д" || children != "н"){
                System.Console.WriteLine("Введите ответ, подходящий требованиям.");
            }
        }
        public int procent = 3;
        public void countProcent() {
            if(age >= 60){
                procent -= 1;
            }
            if(salary <= 35000){
                procent -= 1;
            }else if(salary >= 50000){
                procent += 2;
            }else if(salary >= 80000){
                procent += 3;
            }else if(salary >= 150000){
                procent += 5;
            }
            if(childrenMany >= 3){
                procent -= 1;
            }else if(childrenMany >= 6){
                procent -= 2;
            }
            if(rating == -1){
                procent += 3;
            }else if(rating == 1){
                procent -= 1;
            }
            if(procent < 1){
                procent = 1;
            }else if(procent > 7){
                procent = 7;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `procent` ==> `client.procent`?

Comment: а вообще, лучше бы ваш метод `countProcent` возвращшал число, его бы и использовали

Comment: большое спасибо! :)